# Line character replacement while opening json file with python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pandas

I have a json file and at some lines I found

```
{"fruit": "C", "opinion": "too bitter", "country": "X"},
{"fruit": "D", "opinion": "too bitter but "sometimes" sweet", "country": "Y"},
{"fruit": "A", "opinion": "salt "and" ok", "country": "Z"},
```

How can I automate the following code?

```
with open("fruits.json", "rt") as f:
    with open("fruit_f.json", "wt") as f2:
        for i in f:
            f2.write(i.replace('"sometimes"', 'sometimes'))
```

My problem is that the strings (or numbers) inside " " can change and I can not track each one of them because it is a huge file. 
Is it possible to use re.sub ? 
If not possible to open as json, is there any way to transform it to a pandas df?

Comment: there is pandas.read_json()

Comment: I Know. Already tried it, but it does not work.
ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding object value

Comment: This looks like the same question as yesterday. Why the duplicate?

Comment: I wrote wrong info about the file yesterday.

Comment: Is it a big file? (I mean file size). Can you paste it, save and share in https://jsfiddle.net/ for example? If so,  I think maybe I can fix it pretty easily in a code editor with search replace  + some javascript. But I don't know a good regex to solve it, I would just use the methods that I mentioned in the previous question.

Comment: What you actually want to do is replacing (or better escaping?) quotes inside quotes, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hard problem and I can not think of silver bullet to solve this in one shoot with a regex since this is a nested pattern with multiple possible anchors in a recursive structure.

What I can offer is a two-step solution that a) tries to find all data-values enclosed in double quotes and b) replaces unescaped quotes if there are any:

```
import regex as re    
regex = r"(?<=\": \").*?(?=\"\s*[,}])"
input_str = ("{\"fruit\": \"C\", \"opinion\": \"too bitter\", \"country\": \"X\"},\n"
    "{\"fruit\": \"D\", \"opinion\": \"too bitter but \"sometimes\" sweet\", \"country\": \"Y\"},\n"
    "{\"fruit\": \"A\", \"opinion\": \"salt \"and\" ok\", \"country\": \"Z\"},")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1
    ##print(match.group().replace('"', '\"'))
    if "\"" in match.group():
        input_str = input_str.replace(match.group(), match.group().replace("\"", "\\\""))
```

As you can see, if there is an unescaped quote the replacement is applied to the input_string.

Output: `print(input_str)`

```
{"fruit": "C", "opinion": "too bitter", "country": "X"},
{"fruit": "D", "opinion": "too bitter but \"sometimes\" sweet", "country": "Y"},
{"fruit": "A", "opinion": "salt \"and\" ok", "country": "Z"},
```

And, finally, you should end up with a valid JSON file.